# Empty Pandas DataFrame when I Read Teradata Query

Tags: python, pandas, teradata

I get the header of the pandas dataframe and zero rows when I execute:

```py
import teradata
import pandas as pd

# teradata connection
udaExec = teradata.UdaExec(appName="Example", version="1.0",
                           logConsole=False)
with udaExec.connect(method="odbc", system="", username="", password="") as session:


    query ="SELECT * FROM table"

    df = pd.read_sql(query,session)
```

How do I run teradata Query Into Pandas DataFrame?

Comment: are you sure the table is not blank?

Comment: I execute that query and I get: 0 rows × 35 columns (35 columns it's the number of columns of the database I'm querying)

Comment: Please run same query in Teradata (outside Python) and advise what results. This is what @MEdwin actually means.